# How to find $\lim_{t\to0}\bigg(\int_0^1[bx+a(1-x)]^tdx\bigg)^{1/t}$

Tags: calculus

If $0\lt a\lt b$, I'm trying to find:

$$\lim_{t\to0}\bigg(\int_0^1[bx+a(1-x)]^tdx\bigg)^{1/t}$$

Solving the integral by substitution we have:

$$\lim_{t\to 0}\bigg(\frac{1}{b-a}\cdot\frac{b^{t+1}-a^{t+1}}{t+1}\bigg)^{1/t}$$

I don't how to proceed.

What I know:

- This identity
  $b^{t+1}-a^{t+1}=(b-a)(b^t+b^{t-1}a+\ldots+ba^{t-1}+a^t)$
- This limit is in the form: $1^{\infty}$.

I think I'm close, I need a hand how to find this limit.

Comment: Take logs then L'Hopital is my best guess

Comment: That identity is only true for integer $t$, not $t \to 0$.

Comment: @martycohen Good point!

Answer (score 4):

Apply l'Hospital's rule to the limit of the logarithm of the given integral. This leads to:
$$
\lim_{t \to 0} \left( \frac{\log( \int_{0}^{1} [bx + a(1-x)]^t \mathrm dx ) }{t} \right) = \lim_{t \to 0} \left( \frac{\int_{0}^{1} [bx + a(1-x)]^t \log [bx + a(1-x)] \mathrm dx}{\int_{0}^{1} [bx + a(1-x)]^t \mathrm dx} \right) = \int\limits_{0}^{1} \log [bx + a(1-x)] \mathrm dx = \frac{1}{b-a} (\log \frac{b^b}{a^a})-1\,.
$$
Above, use of [Leibniz's integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) was made. Consequently, the desired limit is

> $$
> e^{-1}\left(\frac{b^b}{a^a}\right)^{1/(b-a)}
> $$

Comment: We agree. Yours is a lot simpler.

Comment: Please could you explain the first equality?

Answer (score 2):

suppose we make a change of variable $y = bx + a(1-x),$ then we have $$\begin{align}\int_0^1[bx+a(1-x)]^tdx &= \frac1{b-a}\int_a^by^t \, dt\\
&=\frac{b^{t+1} - a^{t+1}}{(b-a)(t+1)}
\end{align}$$

now we also have 
$$\begin{align}\lim_{t\to 0}\left( \frac{b^{t+1} - a^{t+1}}{b-a}\right)^{1/t} &= \lim_{t\to 0} \left(\frac{e^{(1+t)\ln b} - e^{(1+t)\ln a}}{b-a}\right)^{1/t}\\
 &=\left(\frac{b(1+t\ln b+\cdots)-a(1 + t\ln a+\cdots)}{b-a}\right)^{1/t}\\
&=\left(1 +t(b\ln b - a\ln a + \cdots)\right)^{1/t}\\
&=e^{(b\ln b - a \ln a)/(b-a)}\\
\lim_{t \to 0}(1 + t)^{1/t} &= e\end{align}$$ 
therefore $$ \lim_{t\to0}\left(\int_0^1[bx+a(1-x)]^tdx\right)^{1/t} = e^{-1+(b\ln b - a \ln a)/(b-a)}.$$

Comment: Looks like mine, so has to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Being sloppy whenever
I feel like it:

$\begin{array}\\
\bigg(\int_0^1[bx+a(1-x)]^tdx\bigg)^{1/t}
&=\bigg(\int_0^1[a+x(b-a)]^tdx\bigg)^{1/t}\\
&=\bigg(\int_0^1[a+cx]^tdx\bigg)^{1/t}
\qquad\text{where }c = b-a > 0\\
&=\bigg(\frac1{c}\int_a^bu^tdu\bigg)^{1/t}
\qquad u = a+cx, dx = du/c\\
&=\bigg(\frac1{c}\frac{b^{t+1}-a^{t+1}}{t+1}\bigg)^{1/t}
\qquad\text{as user42912 got}\\
&\approx\bigg(\frac1{c}\frac{b^{1+1/n}-a^{1+1/n}}{1+1/n}\bigg)^{n}
\qquad t = 1/n\\
&=\bigg(\frac1{c}\frac{b\,b^{1/n}-a\,a^{1/n}}{1+1/n}\bigg)^{n}\\
&\approx\bigg(\frac1{c}\frac{b(1+\ln b/n)-a(1+\ln a/n)}{1+1/n}\bigg)^{n}\\
&\approx\bigg(\frac1{c}\frac{b-a+(b\ln b-a\ln a)/n}{1+1/n}\bigg)^{n}\\
&\approx\bigg(\frac{b-a}{c(1+1/n)}+\frac1{c}\frac{(b\ln b-a\ln a)/n}{1+1/n}\bigg)^{n}\\
&=\bigg(\frac{n}{n+1}+\frac1{c}\frac{b\ln b-a\ln a}{n+1}\bigg)^{n}\\
&=\bigg(1-\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{c}\frac{b\ln b-a\ln a}{n+1}\bigg)^{n}\\
&=\bigg(1+\frac1{c}\frac{b\ln b-a\ln a-c}{n+1}\bigg)^{n}\\
&\approx\exp\bigg(\frac{b\ln b-a\ln a-c}{b-a}\bigg)
\qquad\text{since }(1+x/n)^n \approx e^x\\
&\approx\exp\bigg(\frac{b\ln b-a\ln a}{b-a}-1\bigg)\\
&=\frac1{e}\bigg(\frac{b^b}{a^a}\bigg)^{\frac1{b-a}}
\end{array}
$

And that's what I get.

As a check,
if $a=0$ and $b=1$,
the expression is

$\begin{array}\\
\left(\int_0^1 x^t dt\right)^{1/t}
&=\left(\frac{x^{t+1}}{t+1}|_0^1\right)^{1/t}\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{t+1}\right)^{1/t}\\
&\to \frac1{e}
\qquad\text{since } (1+t)^{1/t} \to e\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: I didn't understand why you made $b^{1/n}\approx 1+\ln b/n$. Thank you!

Comment: $b^{1/n} = e^{\ln b/n} \approx 1+\ln b/n$ for large $n$ since $e^x \approx 1+x$ for small $x$.